# How to test if an attribute exists in some XML

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have some XML that I am parsing in python via lxml.

I am encountering situations where some elements have attributes and some don't.

I need to extract them if they exist, but skip them if they don't - I'm currently landing with errors (as my approach is wrong...)

I have deployed a testfornull, but that doesn't work in all cases:

Code:

```
if root[0][a][b].attrib == '<>': 
 ByteSeqReference = "NULL"
else:
 ByteSeqReference = (attributes["Reference"])
```

XML A:

```
<ByteSequence Reference="BOFoffset">
```

XML B:

```
<ByteSequence Endianness = "little-endian" Reference="BOFoffset">
```

XML C:

```
<ByteSequence Endianness = "little-endian">
```

XML D:

```
 <ByteSequence>
```

My current method can only deal with A, B or D. It can not cope with C.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I'm surprised that a test for null values on an attribute which often won't exist works *ever* -- what you should be doing is checking whether it exists, not whether it's empty:

```
if 'Reference' in current_element.attrib:
  ...do something with it...
```

Comment: Ahhh. thats how it works. (I was surprised too.... ). Thanks for your time, I appreciate it. That completely fixes it.